# Adding class selector makes code not work, why?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar in the process of learning html/css. When I take out the .navigation class reference from before the ul, li, and li a elements in the CSS, the code works, but if I don't it doesn't work. Why? To my understanding, if I put ul.navigation, it should be no different. This doesn't change this code, as there is only 1 list, but if there were multiple, it would create problems.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="math.html">Math</a></li>
            <li><a href="science.html">Science</a></li>
            <li><a href="english.html">English Vinglish</a></li>
            <li><a href="language.html">Language</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <h2>header</h2>
        <p>A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    overflow: scroll;
    border-color: black;
}

.navigation {
    position: relative;;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    z-index: -1100;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("red.jpg");
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    /*color: white;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "work"? What do you mean by "work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul.navigation` doesn't work because you have no `ul` element that is a member of the `navigation` class.

The only element that is a member of the `navigation` class is a `div`.

HTML classes are not inherited by their descendants.

You can use a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) though:

```
.navigation ul { ... }
```

Comment: so I can do either
`div.navigation ul` or  `<li class="navigation">`

Comment: @AlS I think you meant to say "... or `<ul class="navigation">`.